# What if a constructor parameter has the same name as a member variable in C++?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, gcc, initialization

Some code first:

```
class CInner {
public:
    CInner( const CInner& another ) { //impl here }
private:
    // some member variables
}

class COuter {
public:
    COuter( const CInner& inner ) : inner( inner ) {}
private:
    CInner inner;
}
```

Yes, in `COuter::COuter( const CInner& )` the parameter has the same name as the member variable.

In VC++ that works - VC++ gets the idea that it is only reasonable to initialize the member variable with the parameter and that's what happens - `CInner::inner` gets initialized with the parameter. But when the same is compiled with GCC it is interpreted in another way: GCC initializes `CInner::inner` *with itself* and so it is left uninitialized.

Which of the compilers is right?

Comment: What makes you think gcc initializes `inner` with itself?

Comment: @gf: We've been hit by this big time when porting some of VC++ code.

Comment: I would check your GCC claim is correct as that has never, ever happened with me. Make sure you spelled the parameter correctly.

Comment: There must be some other issue, no GCC version i know had a problem with that and its standard-conform. Your description doesn't match your code by the way - you talk about `CInner::inner` but in the code there is only `COuter::inner`.

Comment: Whether the compiler does this right is one thing. But what makes you think humans won't be confused by this?

Comment: An example that shows the problem would be useful. How do you determine how `inner` has been initialized?

Comment: @sbi: Humans will be confused first, then say "Who cares? VC++ does it right." then they go to lengths explaining why it does it right and it is kept as is. And then other people port this to GCC and the WTF per minute gets really high.

Comment: @sth: If CInner is for example something like MFC::CRect it is very easy to see that it's values contain garbage instead of what was passed into the COuter::COuter().

Comment: @sharptooth: Well, I *did* try it and it was very easy to see that in my case everything got initialized correctly. That's why I'm asking how exactly the problematic case should look like.

Comment: I used to do it with GCC in the past, and I just tested it with the current version of GCC that I currently use. As far as I remember, it worked correctly in the past and it works correctly now. What version of GCC are you using?

Comment: @AndreyT: That was GCC 3.3 on White Box Linux.

Comment: @sharptooth: Weird. Every recent version of GCC does this correctly though.

Comment: At least provide compilable code that demonstrates the problem. Half the problem in code (that does not compile) and half the problem in English with wild assumptions about how it works is __NOT__ useful. Compilable code that produces output to show your point is much better and will usually answer the questions.

Answer (score 25):

It is not really about some specific compiler deciding what's reasonable and what's not. The language specification explicitly says that in `inner(inner)` used in the constructors initializer list the first `inner` should be looked up in class scope (i.e. resolve to `COuter::inner`), while the second `inner`should  be looked up in the constructor scope (i.e. resolve to constructor parameter `inner`).

This is what you described as VC++ behavior. However, I find it hard to believe that GCC would behave incorrectly in this case (unless you have some weird old version of GCC). Are you sure you haven't misinterpreted GCC's behavior somehow?

Comment: This issue can be avoided by simply using two different variable names.  The different names also add to the readability, IMHO.

Answer (score 12):

Visual C++ is correct. I suspect you're using an older version of gcc for your test -- at least as I recall, recent ones do this correctly. This is covered in §12.6.2/7 of the standard, which gives the following example:

```
class X {

    int a;
    int b;
    int i;
    int j;

public:
    const int& r;

    X(int i): r(a), b(i), i(i), j(this->i) {}

};
```

> initializes X::r to refer to X::a, initializes X::b with the value of the constructor
>   parameter i, initializes X::i with the value of the constructor parameter i, [ ...]

Comment: It may be right but it is ugly as all hell and makes it more difficult to read than needs be.

Comment: @Craig: How so? I'd say "difficult to read" is when you have to keep track of two different names for what's conceptually the same object. Of course the member and the constructor parameter should have the same name. They're *supposed* to be the same.

Comment: i keep the practice of keeping my private member variables in a certain format such as m_variable, i think this is pretty standard and it avoids these conflicts.
I just don't think it makes sense to have two variables with the same name; even if one if a member variable and one is a parameter. Everyone has a point where they think things just become too difficult to bother with, for me it is having two variable with the same name in the same function, plus m_i(i) is easier to conceptualize than i(i).